# How to convert Android's DP to Flutter's LP? What is the difference between DP and LP?

Tags: mobile, flutter, pixel, units-of-measurement

I got the designs for a new app. All the dimensions are Android-ready and are given in DP - (*Density-independent Pixels*). How can I convert these values to **Flutter's LP** (*Logical Pixels*). 
I know that `Window.devicePixelRatio` gives me the number of device pixels for each logical pixel.

What's the exact difference between DP and LP?
Are there any built-in methods for dp to lp conversion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the documentation ([`FlutterView.devicePixelRatio`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html) and [Flutter for Android Developers](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#where-do-i-store-my-resolution-dependent-image-files)), there is no real difference between DP and LP.

> Device pixels are also referred to as physical pixels. Logical pixels are also referred to as device-independent or resolution-independent pixels.
>
> Flutter doesn’t have `dp`s but there are logical pixels, which are basically the same as device-independent pixels. The so-called devicePixelRatio expresses the ratio of physical pixels in a single logical pixel.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html there are roughly 38 logical pixels per centimeter, or about 96 logical pixels per inch, of the physical display.

And according to [https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities，One](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities%EF%BC%8COne) dp is a virtual pixel unit that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi; the "baseline" density).

So we can say：

160 dp == 1 inch == 96 lp

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code below to make your mobile screen responsive :

```
double getHeight(double screenHeightofthedeviceYouAreDebuging,BuildContextcontext,double size)
{

     return (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / screenHeight) * size;

}
```

SO if you are debugging with 5 in screen the height of the screen will be 640 or MediaQuery.of(context).size. ( width and height ) will give you the screen size of the testing device 
`screen Height of the device You Are Debuging = 640`
`context = BuildContext`
`size = size you want to be as you image , container etc height` .
So it will convert the size of the screen according to the device used

```
double getWidth(double screenWidthofthedeviceYouAreDebuging,BuildContext context,double size){

  return (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / screenHeight) * size;

}

EdgeInsets padding(top,bottom,left,right,context){
    return EdgeInsets.only(
      top: getHeight(640, context, top),
      bottom: getHeight(640, context, bottom),
      left: getHeight(640, context, left),
      right: getHeight(640, context, right));
}
```